# Find first element of array and show it in map function but have warning - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have data like so:

```
    {
      "title": 0,
      "name": 0,
      "score": 0,
      "summary": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "start": "2019-11-01",
          "end": "2019-11-04"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "start": "2019-11-01",
          "end": "2019-11-04"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am trying to access the first element of summary, so I have tried this:

```
    const newDate = new Date(data?.summary.map((d: any, index: number) => {
               if (index === 0) {
                 return (
                 new Date(d.start)
               )
          }
     })),
```

although it's working i get the warning:

**Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return**

I know it must be because I am not returning anything in the callback and the return is in the if statement?

Comment: Why using map in the first place instead of direct accesss to the array element?

Comment: Why not `data?.summary[0]?.start`

Comment: Over thinking the issue, thanks that did work

Answer (score 1):

```
if (index === 0) {
                 return (
                 new Date(d.start)
               )
```

You are only returning a value if index === 0.

Im not sure what are you trying to achieve:

```
const newDate = new Date(data?.summary.map((d: any, index: number) => {
           if (index === 0) {
             return (
             new Date(d.start)
           )
      }
 })),
```

I suppose:

```
const newDate = newDate(data?.summary[0]?.start)
```

Will do the thing.

Comment: So what would be the workaround?

Comment: See my updated post. When you are dealing with a single value rather than with an array, you dont need map or any other method of array.

Comment: Over thinking the issue, thanks that did work

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the first element without using `map` function:

```
const newDate = new Date(data?.summary[0].start)
```

Comment: Over thinking the issue, thanks that did work